# The series may converge, but what about the series / n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $a_i$ be a positive sequence such that $a_i \to 0$.

I know that the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ may be divergent.

But what about the series divided by $n$; does the following go to 0?

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n} \to^{n\to \infty} 0$$

In Wikipedia there are many [convergence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests), but here the question is not exactly about convergence of series, so I don't know where to start...

Comment: You should read about [Cesàro summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).

Comment: @Tom-Tom Thanks! I think the more relevant link is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean : it says that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = A$ then also $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = A$, where $c_n$ is exactly my sequence. So the answer to my question is yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to provide a proof:

$a_i \to 0$, so for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is some $N_0$ such that for all $n\gt N_0$ you have $|a_i| \lt \epsilon/2$

Let $s_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j$ and $c_n=\frac{s_n}{n}$.  Then consider $N_1 = \lceil N_0+2|s_{N_0}|/\epsilon \rceil$.

For all $n\gt N_1$ you have:
$$
|s_n| \leq |s_{N_0}| + \left|\sum_{j=N_0+1}^n a_j\right| \lt |s_{N_0}| + (n-N_0)\epsilon/2 
$$
On the other hand:
$$
n \epsilon = n\epsilon/2 + n\epsilon/2 \geq n\epsilon/2 + N_1\epsilon/2 \geq 
n\epsilon/2 + N_0\epsilon/2 + |s_{N_0}| = |s_{N_0}| + (n+ N_0)\epsilon/2
$$
Combining the last two inequalities gives: $|s_n|\leq n\epsilon$, 
so $|c_n| \lt \epsilon$, implying $c_i \to 0$.